Multiple models in a singular view Django
Can somone tell me how I can make a CreateView and an UpdateView using two different models?
I have two models and I want to be able to create a CreateView and an UpdateView for both an Album and a Review. I want all of the information to be saved using the same fourm to their respective tables. I know how to do this when i create a view for only one model, but i dont know how to do it when i have two or more models. In other words i want the url to open the fourm for the album and the review, input all the information and press submit, once i press submit i want both of them to be saved to my database.
My code for the models :
  class Album(models.Model):
   artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   ...

class Review(models.Model):
   reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   rating = models.IntegerField(
      validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)],
      default=10,
   )
   comment = models.TextField()
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

